# QGIS proj4 definition is not valid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, proj

In QGIS 3.4 I'm trying to add a custom projection that was used for topographic maps of Suriname in the 1950s. I have the parameters from an article about historical CRS used in the country. Using the proj documentation I defined the custom CRS. I even tested it and the returned coordinates confirm that the projection does what I want. However, when I click OK to add the custom CRS, I get the popup: "The proj4 definition of 'Roussilhe Suriname' is not valid."
[image: error message]

Here is the proj string:

```
 +proj=rouss +lat_0=4.11667 +lon_0=-55.68333 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=300000 +y_0=775000 +ellps=bessel +units=km +no_defs
```

How can I test it, but then get the message that the definition is invalid? In any case, I now very little about proj4 and can't find the error. Below is a snip of the article containing the parameters.
[image: Source: PHOTOGRAMMETRIC ENGINEERING & REMOTE SENSING]

Comment: Please copy your proj definition also as text for making it easy to copy and paste.

Comment: The [Roussilhe documentation](https://proj.org/operations/projections/rouss.html) doesn't list lat_0 has a supported parameter. You might try dropping the parameter as a check even though that will affect the Y/northing values. Also maybe try making the output values meters versus km. Both are guesses.

Comment: @user30184 I've added the proj definition as text.

Comment: In QGIS 3.11 the test does not run but it gives the same error immediately.

Comment: Gdaltransform gives results with `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs "+proj=rouss +lat_0=4.11667 +lon_0=-55.68333 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=300000 +y_0=775000 +ellps=bessel +units=km +no_defs"`. Perhaps you should write mail to qgis users mailing list. BTW the false easting/northing values may be wrong if the unit is km and if proj really interprets the given units.

Comment: Dropping the lat_0 and changing the units to m didn't gave me the wrong output coordinates and I still got the error.

Comment: @user30184 what do you mean that the false easting/northing might be wrong? Proj documentation states that these are always in meters, even if a different unit is given as parameter. I will post to the users mailing list

Comment: Ok, I would trust in the documentation then.

Comment: @Gin: this happens to me too, with a CORDEX rotated pole projection (`"+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=lonlat +o_lon_p=-162.0 +o_lat_p=39.25 +lon_0=180.0 +ellps=WGS84"`). The lack of detail in the QGIS error is annoying. Did you end up posting to the mailing list?

Comment: @naught101 I had sent an email to the user list but it never got posted. I still don't have a solution to this

Comment: @user30184 Dec 14 '19 at 15:49 I get this error message: gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs "+proj=rouss +lat_0=4.11667 +lon_0=-55.68333 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=300000 +y_0=775000 +ellps=bessel +units=km +no_defs"
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
+proj=rouss +lat_0=4.11667 +lon_0=-55.68333 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=300000 +y_0=775000 +ellps=bessel +units=km +no_defs

Comment: @HansErren What is QGIS version? In v3.18.1, it works, there is no error.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz you are correct; I was using QGIS 3.8 with C:\>gdaltransform --version
GDAL 2.4.1, released 2019/03/15. I installed QGIS 3.18 now it runs without error, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error adding a new CRS. After a few try's I could finally add my CRS adding quotation marks to the name, in your case changing **Roussilhe Suriname** for **"Roussilhe Suriname"**. After adding the CRS you can edit the name removing the quotation marks.

Comment: The quotation marks workaround did not work for me (Windows 10, QGIS 3.8) and where do you edit to remove the quotation marks?

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bug in that QGIS version. It works as expected in QGIS 3.10.14, 3.16.5, 3.18.1 (tested).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly an answer to the question asked, but someone may end up here with the same problem as I.

I had an 'empty' CRS line (blue line in the screenshot) and accidentally I tried to add another one and set the definition for that 'second' one. Even though all data for the second one was correct, when clicking ok, it failed with the error message "The definition of '' is not valid". After removing the first 'empty' CRS line with the minus, it worked.

[image]

Comment: That empty entry fooled me as well, well spotted !

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with whitespaces.
New versions of QGIS want spaces before every plus sign except the first one.